# a proper mapping is a closed mapping

Tags: general-topology

If a continuous function between locally compact Hausdorff spaces is proper (i.e. preimages of compact sets are compact), then it is also closed.
How to prove it?

Answer (score 2):

A much more general theorem holds.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

(cited from “General Topology” by Ryszard Engelking. )